# Error while using Sobel edge detection method

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sobel

```
img = cv2.imread('skeleton.JPG')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0,ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1,ksize=5)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(sobelx, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

I'm getting error as follows,

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-3e640684ed0a> in <module>
----> 1 plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(sobelx, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

error: OpenCV(4.2.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. What would a useful answer be? Tell you why you get the error? Tell you how to fix the error? Please be explicit!

Comment: That said, your error message is very clear: `CV_64F` is an unsupported depth. Try using a different depth value.

Answer (score 0):

In the Sobel operation, after computing `sobelx` and `sobely` you have to compute `np.sqrt(sobelx ** 2 + sobely ** 2)`. After that you should choose a threshold to find edges. Moreover, you will get a black and white image, so you can't convert it to RGB or BGR image.
The right code will be:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

threshold = 6.

img = cv2.imread('skeleton.JPG')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) / 255

sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)
sobel_xy = np.sqrt(sobelx ** 2 + sobely ** 2)
edge_image = np.float32(sobel_xy > threshold)

plt.imshow(edge_image, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

If you want to display `sobelx` you can apply `np.abs` and normalize it and then show:

```py
sobelx_disp = np.abs(sobelx)
sobelx_disp = sobelx_disp / np.max(sobelx_disp)
plt.imshow(sobelx_disp, 'gray')
plt.show()
```